# Is there a standard around encryption of HTTP query strings?

Tags: http, encryption, query-string

Please suggest any widely used query parameter encryption technique that works best for common servers and client side libraries?

The requirement is to encrypt entire query string right after the '?' so that no field names or values can be read in clear.

Is there any HTTP level standard for the same?
One of the ways could be,

```
mycommerce.com/gp/goldbox?gb_f_GB-SUPPLE=sortOrder:BY_SCORE,enforcedCategories:165796011&pf_rd_p=2208383682&pf_rd_s=slot-3&pf_rd_t=701
```

would become

```
mycommerce.com/gp/goldbox?params=<encrypted string>
```

Comment: This is very broad, if not opinion-based. Please explain what data you want encrypt and why. Also explain why you don't just use HTTPS.

Comment: I do understand that query params are not used for anything sensitive and SSL takes care of channel encryption. In this case traffic between servers within an internal domain is not SSL enabled. However to avoid logging query params in clear text encryption option came up. The data in query param would be mostly filter criteria. But still data that need not be logged.

Comment: More details added. Should this now be responded to?

Comment: No, there's no standard. How are those URLs generated? Do you need access to query string parameters in JavaScript? Do you have GET forms?

Comment: It is about protecting the query string in situations such as when are in the web server-log, after SSL offloading is done.  Yes javascript  and browsers would need to access these GET urls.